# Can not show a default value in ng-select

Tags: angularjs

I have following code. I want to show a value in `select` from `infoData`--> `selection` field, but failed.

```
<tbody>                 
    <tr ng-repeat="emp in infoData">
        <td>                              
            <input name="selection{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.name"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[{{$index}}]" />
        </td>
        <td>          
          <select name="name{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.selection" ng-options="employe.id as employe.name for employe in designationList" ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[{{$index}}]"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input name="email{{$index}}" ng-model="emp.email"  ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[{{$index}}]"/>
        </td>                            
        <td >
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" ng-click="editEmployee($index)">Edit</button>
            <!--<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="deleteEmployee($index)">Delete</button>-->
          </div>  
        </td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

How to select selection value in `infoData` in `select` ?

```
$scope.infoData = [
        { name: $scope.applicant, selection: "Debtor", email:"a@gmail.com"},
        { name: $scope.secureParty, selection:"Secured Party", email:"b@gmail.com"}
    ];
```

and

```
$scope.designationList = [
    {name:"Debtor", id:"1"},
    {name:"Secured Party", id:"2"}

];
```

[image]

Here I want to see a selected value in `select`

Comment: what is `enabledEdit`? and `ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[{{$index}}]"` should be `ng-disabled="!enabledEdit[$index]"`

Comment: `enabledEdit[{{$index}}]` is another array to make decission whether it sould be enabled or disabled.

Comment: if you use `employe.id as employe.name`, just set the selected value to what corresponds to the `id` field: `{ name: $scope.applicant, selection: '1', email:"a@gmail.com"},`

Comment: @kaddath Thanks. It works.